# onActivityResult return before pick up image

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I need to pick an image with onActivityResult, but onActivityResult not wait to user for pick up.

I tried some different samples, nothing changed.

Here onActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Log.i("onActivityResult", "onActivityResult started!");
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) 
    {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        Log.i("onActivityResult", "onActivityResult");
        //ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        //imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

    }
```

And here how i call :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) 
    {
        //something
        return true;
    }
    else if (id == R.id.cikis) 
    {
        //something         
        return true;
    }
    else if ( id == R.id.background)
    {
        Log.i("background", "clicked to background!");

        Intent i = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I don't understand why. Im stuck on here.

**SOLVED!**

I delete to **android:launchMode="singleInstance"** (inside  tag ) line in manifest, than it's work correctly!

Comment: If it does not wait then when is it executed?